# Complex (I think) nth-child selector required

Tags: css

I need a complex nth-child selector and I am drawing a blank, it would probably help if I listed 20 items to show what I am trying to do:

1: background: #fdf0e8;

2: background: #e7ebf2;

3: background: #e7f2f3;

4: background: #fdf0e8;

5: background: #fdf0e8;

6: background: #e7ebf2;

7: background: #e7f2f3;

8: background: #fdf0e8;

9: background: #fdf0e8;

10: background: #e7ebf2;

11: background: #e7f2f3;

12: background: #fdf0e8;

13: background: #fdf0e8;

14: background: #e7ebf2;

15: background: #e7f2f3;

16: background: #fdf0e8;

17: background: #fdf0e8;

18: background: #e7ebf2;

19: background: #e7f2f3;

20: background: #fdf0e8;

Is this even possible, or would I be better using PHP to cycle styles?

Comment: instead of using HEX value use easy values so we can see the pattern ...

Comment: Is this really 4 styles.  You just have to put 1 and 4 twice even though the value is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like shown below. I've added the text color just to make the styling difference more obvious when running the snippet.

```css
.item:nth-child(4n+1), .item:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: #fdf0e8;
  color: lime;
}
.item:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background-color: #e7ebf2;
  color: red;
}
.item:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background-color: #e7f2f3;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Unforunately going to have to go with PHP to cycle styles as I need this in a Slick Slider which adds all sorts of markup to get it going.